# JPA Transient fields with callback methods

Tags: jpa

I have an entity which contains several basic fields A, B and C and one complex field X which is not (should not be) mapped to a database column. The idea is to create X from A, B and C when loading an instance, and to deconstruct X into A, B and C when persisting.

The first logical thing to try was something like:

```
      @Entity
      class Xxx
      {

      private String a;

      @Transient
      private X x;

      @PrePersist
      public void prePersist()
      {
      XParts xp = x.deconstruct();
      a = xp.getA();
      //...
      }
      //...
      }
```

The problem is, when calling entityManager.merge(xxx); x is lost. Something to do with how the @Transients are handled in JPA. @Transient and @PrePersist don't mix. Ok. Can't argue with the specification I guess.

But, what are the alternatives? I really don't need X in database.

The best I could come up with is:

```
    @Column(insertable=false,updatable=false)
    private X x;
```

Which creates column X, which is always null. If it's really the only way, I can live with that, but it seems hackish at best.

I can't be the only one who run into this problem. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: When you call merge, @PreUpdate annotation would be the right to call.

Answer (score 1):

JPA does not provide any PostMerge events, but if you are using EclipseLink you can define a DescriptorEventListener that does have access to postMerge that would allow you to merge your transient attributes.

Comment: I am only using JPA with hibernate and moving to EclipseLink is too late. Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the same "prePersist" method that you have but annotated with @PreUpdate may sort out your issue. Have you tried that?